# Vue.js conditional rendering in older browsers

Tags: javascript, syntax, vue.js

I'm trying to filter a collection by a search term. When I use the es6 syntax and built in features such as string.includes('') it works fine. Unfortunately I have to support a few versions of IE which doesn't have ES6 so I have to write my script in plain javascript in some scenarios.

Working code in chrome but not in IE:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{        
        term: '',
        products: [{ ProductCode: '3 Year Fixed'}, { ProductCode: 'Not fixed '},{ ProductCode: '3 Year Fixed'}, { ProductCode: '4 Year Fixed'}, { ProductCode: '5 Year Fixed'}]
    },
    computed:{
        filteredProducts: function(){
               if(this.term === ''){
                   return this.products;
               }else{
                   return this.products.filter(
                       product => product.ProductCode.includes(this.term));

               }               
        }
    }  
})
```

So I wrote this code which just doesn't work but can't spot why wouldn't:

```
 computed:{
        filteredProducts: function(){
               if(this.term === ''){
                   return this.products;
               }else{
                    return this.products.filter(function(product){
                       return product.ProductCode.idexOf(this.term) !== -1
                   })


               }
```

I checked the documentation and to me it looks identical:

```
computed: {
  evenNumbers: function () {
    return this.numbers.filter(function (number) {
      return number % 2 === 0
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using babel for this, so you don't have to deal with browser compatibility issues yourself: https://babeljs.io

Comment: Also, do you get any errors in your console? `idexOf` looks like a typo for `indexOf`

Comment: I did not get any error on my pc I think i just made a mistake while editing.
Yes I know Babel would be the best solution but I'm afraid we are not allowed to use it for production yet... Also isn't it hard to set up?

Comment: `Babel` is straightforward to setup if you're familiar with bundlers like `webpack`or `browserify` and build tools like `gulp` or `grunt`, it takes a couple of minutes to configure, and all your `ES6` is compiled to work correctly across all browsers. If you're not familiar with these tools then there is a bit of learning curve to understand how to use them, but I think it's worth it in the end.

Comment: Thank you I will look into it

Answer (score 2):

Right the solution is that the context has changed once in the filter function
so I had to cache the `this`.

```
var self = this;
```

Also another solution was to just use the Vue instances property.
`vm.term`